# How to customize jQuery client-side DataTable default search filter with HTML jstree folder structure?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am stuck in customizing the default search filter of client-side jQuery datatable. I have an HTML jstree folder structure and it contains approx 20 main folders and 5 subfolders specific to the main folders. I am using the client-side jQuery datatable to show the data that the folders contain inside them. The default search filter of datatable is also there and it is working properly with all the data in the datatable. But I want to apply a condition in the default search filter of the datatable, that is suppose I have five documents in my main folder and two documents in my main folder's sub-folder. The document names inside the folders are unique.

Now wheneve I am searching the document name in the search filter it is searching it in the both the folders that is main folder and its sub-folder.

If I have selected the main folder than search would be only in the main folder documents and if I am in its sub-folder than search should be specific to its sub-folder documents. This is the issue I am facing.

Along with this I also have two radio buttons above my datatable. The buton names are "Search document in folders" and "Search document is folders and sub-folders". So whenever the first button is selected the search will happen in the main folder only and when the second button is selected then search will happen to both folders and its sub-folders.

Please help me out if anyone have the solution to this situation.

I have tried the default search API given in the docs of jQuery Datatable. Below i am sharing my code.

```
`$(document).on('click', '.jstree-anchor', function() {
var val = $(this).text();
regExSearch = val.trim();
$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(function (oSettings, aData){
    $('#selectFolder').change(function () {                 
        table.columns(16).search(aData[3], true, true).draw();
    });
});
table.column(16).search(regExSearch, true, true).draw();
}
});`
```

Here, aData[3] is my column name that is "Document Name". But I don't want to pass any specific column because I want to search the whole table.

In my code this line is working perfectly

```
`table.column(16).search(regExSearch, true, true).draw();`
```

The "#selectFolder" is the id of my radio button. Only I have to apply conditions to this line according to the radio button changes.